# How a project is installed with npm install command

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation, npm

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

How `phonegap` is installed when I run this command.Reason for my doubt is that, we are not mentioning any ip here, then how and from where it grabs the content?
consider phone gap is just an example.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897908/how-npm-install-works) but not describes the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM grabs and installs its packages from [www.npmjs.org](http://www.npmjs.org).